# Plugin template's are not available from console commands

Tags: plugin-development

The `if` statement on Line 859 of `TemplatesService.php` prevent the template service from loading templates from a plugin.

Is there a specific reason for this, or is it simply a case that hasn't been needed for the command line interface yet?

I would like to use the template service to render various things like report emails. Is there another way I can do this from the CLI at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

> is it simply a case that hasn't been needed for the command line interface yet?

Most likely this one.

Can you send your plugin over to support@buildwithcraft.com and point us to a command that will reproduce it so we can look into it?

Will update the answer here with what we find.